# Кто такой "кубарь"?

Tags: этимология

Катиться с горы кубарем. А кто такой этот "кубарь", откуда пошла поговорка?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь - да, скорее всего имеется в виду игрушка. 
Но не совсем понятно, какая именно.
Если классический волчок , то он обычно с горы не катится.
http://hobbitaniya.ru/andersen/img/andersen046_02.jpg
Ему скорее нужна ровная поверхность.

А вот если другая разновидность, более напоминающая обычное колесо, управляемое специальной палкой - игрушка популярная вплоть до послевоенных годов, но ныне совсем забытая, то почему её называют "кубарем"? Короче, я в некоторой задумчивости.

А вообще слово довольно многозначное. От общежития курсантов-моряков и элементов знаков отличия в Красной Армии (до 43-го года) - и до владельца или рабочего перегонного куба. 
Но других подходящих значений нет. Они либо совсем не вяжутся, либо достаточно новые, что исключает их использование в этом выражении.

//-----

Я понял, что немного погорячился со списком значений. Там еще и ударение разное может быть. В большинстве моих примеров - кубАрь. Но это просто для точности. Игрушку никак не отменяет.

Answer (score 6):

КубАрь — распространённая игрушка древней Руси, разновидность волчка.
Обычно это был цилиндр со стесанным нижним концом до формы конуса и кнутик — веревочка на короткой палке. Кубарь раскручивался при помощи веревочки. Подхлестывая кубарь кнутиком, можно было поддерживать его скорость вращения и заставлять двигаться в нужном направлении.

Answer (score 1):

У Фасмера вот...
Хотя, конечно, уже дан прекрасный ответ. Но не обратиться к этимологическому словарю не могу.
[image: куба'рь]

Answer (score -1):

Рыболовная снасть типа верши. Конической формы и конусом с отверстием для "заплыва" рыбы внутри. Как бы воронка в воронке.

Comment: А как эта снасть катится?